# Buffer overflow exploit

Tags: c, security, exploit

I'm trying to learn some basics in cyber security and have been trying to solve an exercise.
in my exercise, I need to exploit this code in order to bypass the username and get in.
(I know it's very dangerous to use the gets() function, but that's the exercise and I'm trying to solve it within the definitions).
this is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main()
{
    char username[8];
    int allow = 0;
    printf("Enter your username, please: ");
    gets(username);

    if (allow)
    {
        printf("Success");
    }
}
```

I thought about overflowing the buffer with 9 chars, in order to overflow the username variable into the allow variable.
for some reason, I can't do it.
can anyone please help?

Comment: Memory doesn't work like that. Unless they are part of the same block, like a struct, variables are not placed back to back in memory, rather given a spot by the OS.

Comment: For this to work the compiler must place `username` at a lower address than `allow`. We can't know if that is the case. Even if  `username` is at a lower address than `allow` we can't know if the compiler added some "padding/space" between them. So you need to try more than just 9 chars. Try 10, 11, 12, 13..... or do `printf("%p %p\n", (void*)username, (void*)&allow);` then you know where the variables are and you know exactly what input to give.

Comment: thank you all for the answers. i'm not allowed to play with the code, just to try and exploit it. i also thought about giving it some kind of username that has a code in order to inject something (for this to work). as this code goes, as it is, do I have a way to override it?

Comment: For testing no one can stop you from adding that print as suggested above and just try it. Then you can apply your gained knowledge to the original code.

Comment: The compiler  views `allow` as a constant that can be eliminated if optimization is enabled when compiling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot of things can be causing your problem and you would need to

- state what compiler you are using
- what flags you are passing
  as the bare minimum, for anyone to give a good answer.
  A description of the output you get when you *try* to overflow the buffer would also be helpful.

However, assuming you are using `gcc`, your problem is probably that `gcc` inserts canaries/stack-protectors, and that you get a message saying `*** stack smashing detected ***`.

If you try to compile your program with `gcc -fno-stack-protector -o bufoverflow bufoverflow.c` you will turn off the stack-protection and your intuition on how to exploit the program will be correct.

See here for a quick introduction to overflow-mitigations: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow_protection